# How to get another application round icon drawable?

Tags: android, icons

Android Nougat has supported setting round icon for an application.

But I can't find the way to get round icon resource from applicationInfo.

My application needs to show all the application's circular icons, just like a launcher.

Is there any way to get round icon of an application?

Comment: you men the launcher icon?

Comment: I don't really understand what you said, but what I did on mine was to import the icon using Batch Drawable plugin, you can download it from the plugins. And after that I have used the icon as the application icon.

Comment: If you want to use a circular icon as the application icon, just create it, and then save it as a .png file.

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy My application needs to show all the application's circular icons, just like a launcher.

Comment: @Vryin My application needs to show all the application's circular icons, just like a launcher.

Comment: If you can get the images of all the other applications, then you can display it using this circular image view library (https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) so that they appear circular.

Comment: @AbhriyaRoy Not all applications'   circular icons are directly using the white background, I just want to know if there is any way to get the application android:roundIcon attribute

Comment: @Sorcerer Have you figured out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible.

The application package information was parsed by [PackageParser.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageParser.java), and the `android:roundIcon` will be parsed only if `R.bool.config_useRoundIcon` was set to true. It is defined by OEM in frameworks [config.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/config.xml).

If your test device enable the `R.bool.config_useRoundIcon`, you can get the round icon (`android:roundIcon`) by `PackageItemInfo.java`. Otherwise, you can only get the default icon (`android:icon`).

Answer (score 0):

You can manually parse the manifest and look for the `roundIcon` ressource:

```
  fun getRoundIcon(context: Context, applicationInfo: ApplicationInfo): Drawable? {
    try {
      val res = context.packageManager.getResourcesForApplication(applicationInfo)
      res.assets.openXmlResourceParser("AndroidManifest.xml").use {
        var eventType: Int
        while (true) {
          eventType = it.nextToken()
          if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && it.name == "application") {
            for (i in 0 until it.attributeCount)
              if (it.getAttributeName(i) == "roundIcon") {
                return ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(
                  res,
                  Integer.parseInt(it.getAttributeValue(i).substring(1)),
                  null
                )
              }
          }
          if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) break
        }
      }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a way, maybe a bit too late with the response. Based on [G00fy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52937976/15690658)`s answer:

```
public Drawable getRoundIcon(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo, PackageManager packageManager) {
    int eventType = -1;

    try {
        Resources resource = packageManager.getResourcesForApplication(applicationInfo);
        XmlResourceParser resourceParser = resource.getAssets().openXmlResourceParser("AndroidManifest.xml");

        while (eventType != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            eventType = resourceParser.getEventType();
            if (eventType == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
                if (resourceParser.getName().equals("application")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < resourceParser.getAttributeCount(); i++)
                        if (resourceParser.getAttributeName(i).equals("roundIcon")) {
                            return resource.getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(resourceParser.getAttributeValue(i).substring(1)));
                        }
                }
            }

            eventType = resourceParser.next();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getRoundIcon: ", e);
    }

    return packageManager.getApplicationIcon(applicationInfo);
}
```

The only downside is that many apps now use dynamic mask icons which means the system shapes them by desire, so it won't be as helpfull as a couple of years ago.